# How to update the clock after eevery second in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I have tried this code and it compiled successfully but it shows nothing

```js
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {

  good(){
    return(
      new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <h1>{this.setInterval(this.good(),1000)}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

The reference is https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html. I am trying to write it in my local node js environment.
Please provide a simple alternative to make this . I am a beginner .

Comment: check this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/s58moawj/

Comment: Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-timeago for automatic updation of time.

Comment: How to simply render a function repeatedly using setInterval function ?

Comment: Hi Sambit, welcome to SO and React. You need to understand the concept of component life-cycle for a correct implementation. Please read https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html. This page has in-depth explanation and it uses the same example you mentioned. Do take a look at the examples others have posted once you think you got a grasp on the basic concepts. All the best!

Comment: You probably forgot to render the App component into a specific container.

Answer (score 0):

easy, See the official documentation: [reactjs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html#updating-the-rendered-element)

```
class App extends Component {

  good(){
    return(
      new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchData();
      this.update = setInterval(()=>this.good(),1000)
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.update);
      }

       render(){
        return(<h1>this.good()</h1>

      );
 }
```

or
see this: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gwoJZk)

```
function tick() {
  const element = (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
  ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

Comment: I have different file structure . Like app.jsx , main.js, index.html . Example of such setup https://watchdown.com/react-js-environment-setup-using-webpack/     . The code in react js documentation does not work their as render is in different file. Pls help .